# Image doesn't load in mobile device in jquery post callback in MVC application

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have the below jquery `post` method that has a call back function in it which loads image to the img tag. If the size of the bytearray is bigger the image doesn't loads in `iPad` but for small arrays it does.

```
$.post(url, info, function (id) {
     $('#imgPDFView').attr('src', '/Report/Render?ReportId=' + id);
});
```

Render method returns me `FileStreamResult` from MVC controller.

Render method creates a byte array from report server.

Comment: Do you get some errors on the server side?

Comment: Do you set HTTP headers for respective image type?. I.E `context.Response.ContentType = "image/png";`

Comment: @G.Stoynev i return the byte array like fileResult=new FileStreamResult(new MemoryStream(bytes), "image/png");

Comment: How do you define "bigger" vs. small array?

Comment: I am creating an image array from reportviewer's Render method has around 12 frames in it. This is I called bigger.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue by replacing the img tag with iframe.

```
$('#imgPDFView').attr('src', '/Report/Render?ReportId=' + id);
```

Still i had issue with the image width as 100% i resolved like below after loading the iframe

```
var $iFrame = $('#imagePDFView');
$iFrame.load(function () {
     var $img = $(window.frames[0].document).find('img');
     if ($img.length > 0) {
         $img.attr('style', 'width:100%');
     }
});
```